# Google plus api people.search query parameters documentation

Tags: google-api, google-plus

I can't seem to find an official google plus people.search query parameters documentation. on the official page (https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/search) there is only the ambivalent saying: "Specify a query string for full text search of public text in all profiles.".
But how? what about using some 'Geo', some 'by_name', a bit of 'gender'?

sorry if it's appear as a newbie question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you currently cannot search by specifying metadata and scope to type on results. You can carefully craft your queries to find strings that match your target, however, and I don't recommend doing this. Please file an issue request on the [Google+ issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/list).